# Artificial Intelligence of 2D Sidescroller in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, artificial-intelligence, unity3d-2dtools

I'm currently making a game in Unity that's a 2D sidescroller (so all sprites are viewed from the side).

I have procedurally generated terrain (so think Terraria-esque), and I want to be able to click on one of my tiles and have a sprite path to it.

However, the sprite needs to know the following things:

1. Whether or not the tile is accessible (aka it's not completely underground or way up randomly in the sky)
2. What the shortest path is to get there.

I'm currently storing my tiles as a short array.

Knowing this, is A* the best algorithm for me to pursue? Does anyone have any other good info/tips of where to begin looking into this sort of thing?

My main conceptual difficulty is making it so the AI knows whether or not a tile is accessible.

Any help/pointers is appreciated!

Comment: What about Unity's built-in navmesh?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D doesn't Unity's Navmesh operate on the x-z axis while the 2D system operates on the x-y axis?

Answer (score 1):

A* is good way to find the shortest path, but it is heavy to use to find if there is a path at all. This is because it is searching the whole accessible space before realizing that there is no path. You can use [this online tool](http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/?utm_content=bufferd26da&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) to play with different search algorithms.

Quick hack you can use to tell if there is a path is store ID for each different space with all nodes accessible to each other. This IDs are easy to assign with recursive function that is going through all accessible nodes. After recursion terminates just start it again with new ID from another space that doesn't yet have any IDs. Hopefully following picture clarifies my point:

```
11111¤22222¤
111¤¤¤222¤¤¤
1¤¤¤3¤¤¤¤¤44
¤¤3333¤¤4444
```

In which `¤` is the walls and numbers are the ids of the spaces. Of course you need to change your storage from short array to something else, because you need to store extra short for each node.

Comment: Hmm. So what you're saying is assign groups of ID's for spaces, and then if blocks have the same ID, they're accessible?

Comment: Yes. You cannot make cheaper test than that. And I think that assigning the IDs is O(2 * n) (which is quite good and you only have to do it once). Because you can loop through every node and every time you find one without an ID, start the recursive ID setter. All launches of the recursive function combined will go through each space node only once.